# Android URI parsing cannot find image

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

This function:

```
public Uri convertURI(Context context, Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Profile", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

The created URI path is this when I send it through an intent into another activity as a string:

```
02-02 22:02:54.471 23398-23398/recruitr.recruitr E/cand_uri_string: content://media/external/images/media/76268
```

Now when I try to use the URI to access the image again, I get this (using the universal image loader library) - it can't find the image:

```
02-02 22:04:07.597 24662-24662/recruitr.recruiter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: recruitr.recruitr, PID: 24662
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration.defaultDisplayImageOptions' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.loadImageSync(ImageLoader.java:597)
                                                                   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.loadImageSync(ImageLoader.java:543)
                                                                   at recruitr.recruitr.CandidateProfile.CandidateProfilePreview_Fragment.onCreateView(CandidateProfilePreview_Fragment.java:84)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18795)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18795)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18795)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18795)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18795)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18795)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2658)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18795)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.
```

Does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: Where calling `defaultDisplayImageOptions ` method ?

Comment: In another activity/fragmnet , in which you are intend to send URI has initialize the universal image loader object??

Comment: Yes to both, that defaultDisplayImageOptions is from the library. I saved the image file in activity A, got the uri in activity A, put it through an intent and retrieved it in activity B, used that to grab the uri from the string extra, but now it is throwing that when I try to get the bitmap from the uri path

Comment: Add "file://"  before URI Path load to ImageView using Universal Imageloader.

Answer (score 2):

Try these lines of code for loading image on the `Imageview` using `Universal` `imageloader` using `URI`

```
private final DisplayImageOptions options;
private final ImageLoader imageLoader;    

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loader)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.loader)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.loader)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

You have to use the `"file://"` in `displayImage` method of `Univeral` `Imageloader`

```
imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + YOUR_URI_HERE, YOUR_IMAGEVIEW, options, null);
```

Comment: I get this: 02-02 22:19:52.230 2551-3213/recruitr.recruitr E/ImageLoader: content:/media/external/images/media/76273: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                              java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/media/external/images/media/76273: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: That's after i added the file://

Comment: @lawonga ..Did you have check that in your sd card that your file or image exit or not?

Comment: IS yours URI path is right or not??..Firstly make check that these Image Uri is exit through code..And after get exact path you should provide that path to the Image loader Uri option

Comment: @lawonga .. If it is useful for you than please mark right these answer :)

Comment: No.. it didn't work. I used another method instead, manually storing it into private storage.

Comment: Means...problem is in the exact path of the Image uri from the sd card ??